# Error message when uploading document, but document still uploads

Tags: sharepoint-server

I'm using SharePoint 2013. My users are uploading documents but getting "Sorry, something went wrong. An unexpected error has occurred" after they click Save.

However, the documents are being successfully uploaded, at that moment, with all the metadata the users added.  I looked up the correlation ID in the server logs and I don't get a clear error message I can look up.

All I get is `"Name=Request (GET:http://intranet/_layouts/15/routermessage.aspx?FileName=ERROR%2520TEST&MType=Success&Fnl=http://intranet/Intranet%2520Documents/ERROR%2520TEST.pdf&Source=/DropOffLibrary&IsD1g=1"`

Does anyone know what might be causing this, or how I might fix it?

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Clear IE cache.
2. Reset IE settings. Go to IE->internet options->advanced tab->reset.
3. Switch to other browsers.
4. Create a new document library to check if the same issue will occur.

Updated:

In my opinion, there is something wrong in the original document library.

Did you add some customizations in the original document library?

The current workaround for the issue, you could move the content from the problematical document library to the new document library.

Comment: I tried the first 3 steps and nothing happened.  However, the 4th step seems to have worked.  I'm not getting an error when I upload documents into the new library.  Anyone know what that might mean?

Comment: I have updated the reply.

Comment: Yes, there are content organizer rules on all our sites through the dropoff library; it's possible that those broke somehow.  I'm not sure if transferring the old content in to the new library is a viable option though, so we'll look into the organizer rules.  Thanks for your help.